# Map view in tab layout throwing , java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized ,Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer

Tags: android

I have created an application which has a tab layout , on clicking on of the tab i open a new activity which uses web view.
Also the other tab uses map view ,list view , image view.

now I installed my application on Samsung Galaxy Y - it was running fine.
When I installed the same app on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 , and when i first open the map view and then the web view and traverse between them i get the following error.

```
08-09 13:00:25.527: E/System(2822): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
08-09 13:00:25.527: E/System(2822): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
08-09 13:00:25.527: E/System(2822):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
08-09 13:00:25.527: E/System(2822):     at android.database.BulkCursorProxy.close(BulkCursorNative.java:288)
08-09 13:00:25.527: E/System(2822):     at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.close(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:133)
08-09 13:00:25.527: E/System(2822):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:49)
08-09 13:00:25.527: E/System(2822):     at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.close(ContentResolver.java:1591)
08-09 13:00:25.527: E/System(2822):     at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.finalize(ContentResolver.java:1604)
08-09 13:00:25.527: E/System(2822):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:182)
08-09 13:00:25.527: E/System(2822):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
08-09 13:00:25.527: E/System(2822):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Any thoughts what might be causing this problem.

Thanks and Regards

Aditya Pratap Singh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same error while deploying my application on a brand new Galaxy Tab 2.
In my case i just open a `MapActivity` that draw some custom `Overlay` and `ItemOverlay` and it throws that error.

I noticed that the map zoom level is set far away so i tought it was the problem: i temporary disabled all drawing stuff of my activity and the map showed correctly, then i zoomed in and exited that activity, i re-enabled my drawing stuff and this time it works correctly (when i opened the activity the zoom level setted was the last i used when i closed the empty map activity)

don't know if it may help you, i suppose it has something to do with incorrect map zoom level at startup so maybe setting a custom zoom level could solve the problem.

Comment: may be , . i don't know . i solved the problem with another way... i was saving the map states whenever i was leaving map activity.