# Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview

Hi i am geting this error. i am using this 
code http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

when i on click of Show place on map this error i am getting. plz asy me solution

```
08-28 16:38:20.554: E/System(4978): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
08-28 16:38:20.554: E/System(4978): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
08-28 16:38:20.554: E/System(4978):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
08-28 16:38:20.554: E/System(4978):     at android.database.BulkCursorProxy.close(BulkCursorNative.java:288)
08-28 16:38:20.554: E/System(4978):     at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.close(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:133)
08-28 16:38:20.554: E/System(4978):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:49)
08-28 16:38:20.554: E/System(4978):     at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.close(ContentResolver.java:1591)
08-28 16:38:20.554: E/System(4978):     at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.finalize(ContentResolver.java:1604)
08-28 16:38:20.554: E/System(4978):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:182)
08-28 16:38:20.554: E/System(4978):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
08-28 16:38:20.554: E/System(4978):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

here is my on clickevent.. i refered samecode from above sample of android hive.. here is my code u u need 
[Can anyone guide me how to get Google Directions between two locations using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067454/can-anyone-guide-me-how-to-get-google-directions-between-two-locations-using-jso)

onclick event

```
btnShowOnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_map);

    // calling background Async task to load Google Places
    // After getting places from Google all the data is shown in listview
    new LoadPlaces().execute();

    /** Button click event for shown on map */
    btnShowOnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlacesMapActivity.class);
            // Sending user current geo location
            Log.i("getLatitude",""+ gps.getLatitude());
            i.putExtra("user_latitude", Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()));
            i.putExtra("user_longitude", Double.toString(gps.getLongitude()));

            // passing near places to map activity
            i.putExtra("near_places", nearPlaces);
            // staring activity
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: show your click events and more code regarding that.

Comment: @PadmaKumar above is my onclick event.

Comment: I am experiencing the same situation. But I do not know what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for getting `Google` directions between two locations. May this help you.

```
double srcLatitude = 0;
double srcLongitude = 0;
Location location = GeoLocationUtil.getGeoLocation(this);
if (GeoLocationUtil.isValidLocation(location)) {
    srcLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    srcLongitude = location.getLongitude();
}

final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
/** Using the web based turn by turn directions url. */
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=" + srcLatitude + ","
    + srcLongitude + "&daddr=" + destLat + "," + destLong));

intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
    "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

as i wrote in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13161591/1716620

i think that the problem is caused by uncorrect zoom level while performing drawing,
try to check your zoom level before performing drawings, i solved that way