# Exception on finalizer daemon

Tags: java, android

I have a weird exception, and I don't know how to approach it.
It happens only on a Galaxy note and only on Android version 4.3.
If someone saw this and knows where it came from or how to deal with it, I would really appreciate some help.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:     android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.finalize() timed out after 15 seconds
android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
android.database.BulkCursorProxy.close(BulkCursorNative.java:214)
android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.close(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:122)
android.database.AbstractCursor.finalize(AbstractCursor.java:434)
java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:188)
java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:171)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Thanks!

p.s.
I googled and found the following threads on stackoverflow, but they did not help:

- [Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158228/uncaught-exception-thrown-by-finalizer)
- [Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer: Google API bug Or Samsung kernel bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112283/uncaught-exception-thrown-by-finalizer-google-api-bug-or-samsung-kernel-bug)

Comment: Are there multiple instances of application running?

Comment: No. But how it can be related?