# Timeout exception from BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor

Tags: android, database, crash, timeout, android-cursor

Here is the crash dump i've got from playstore.

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java)
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
       at android.database.BulkCursorProxy.close(BulkCursorNative.java:214)
       at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.close(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:121)
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.finalize(AbstractCursor.java:470)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:202)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:185)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Device details: 
Lenovo P1a42
Android 6.0.1

Any help on why this crash happens?

Comment: I' ve googled it and find no info regarding this issue.

Comment: Looks like the same crash. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095791/exception-on-finalizer-daemon